# Space Restriction for Client side caching

Tags: java, image, performance, caching

I have a search result page that returns around 40 images. I use mongohq to store my images.
Now these image will never change. They will either be removed or left as is.

So my Spring servlet streams the images after reading from mongoHq based on image id

```
/app/download/{uniqueImageId}
```

All works good. Except the load timings to stream the images. I feel that these images will remain constant for these unique ids so why not cache them. I can add a filter that applies to my above url type and add a caching header, which i plan to give a really long value like maybe cache the images for a week.

My question is, if i start telling the client's browser to cache all these 40+ images, will it cache all these images?
Aren't there any space restrictions from the client side?

Do you see any better option to handle such scenario?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, if i start telling the client's browser to cache all these 40+ images, will it cache all these images? Aren't there any space restrictions from the client side?

Of course, there are space restriction on the client side (also the storage space of the whole world is limited... uhm, sorry for that...). The user may restrict the caching space, and/or the browser just takes automatically the free space available for caching.

Typically I would expect that the browser cache is always some megabytes (let's say 100+), so often needed images, like icons, transfered in a session will be cached. Whether the image is still in the cache, when the user visits your site three days later, depends on the cache size and the users activity in between. So you never know.

What the client or any intermediate proxies do, is out of your direct control. The only thing you do by setting the caching headers is, to say that it is legal not to refresh this resource for a while. Make sure you understand the HTTP1.1 headers correctly, if you do set the headers in your application.

> Do you see any better option to handle such scenario?

The term "better" isn't very exact here. What exactly do you need to optimize?

If you have a lot of requests on the same image set, you can reduce server and database load by putting an edge server, like nginx, in front of your application, which is configured as caching reverse proxy. In this case, your own edge server is interpreting the caching headers. In general, I consider it a good design, if an application has no significant load on serving static resources.